# Image Preivew using AjaxToolKit AsyncFileUpload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to upload image on server side folder using ajaxtoolkit ascyfileuploader but I want to preview that image and want to change name of that image before uploading it on server side.
here is the code..

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptManager1"  runat="server"/>
<div>
    <ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID="fileUpload1" OnClientUploadError="uploadError" 
    CompleteBackColor="White" Width="350px"  runat="server" UploaderStyle="Modern" 
    OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF"  
    ThrobberID="imgLoad"  önUploadedComplete="fileUploadComplete" /><br />
    <asp:Image ID="imgLoad" runat="server" ImageUrl="loading.gif" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="btnhidden" runat="server" />
    <br />


    <asp:Image ID="imgLoader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loader.gif" /><br /><br />
    <img id = "imgDisplay" alt="" src=""  style="display:none;"/>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadComplete(sender, args) {

        var imgDisplay = $get("imgDisplay");
        imgDisplay.src = "images/loader.gif";
        imgDisplay.style.cssText = "";
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            imgDisplay.style.cssText = "height:100px;width:100px";
            imgDisplay.src = img.src;
        };

        <big></big>var myHidden = document.getElementById('<%= btnhidden.ClientID %>');
         var a = myHidden.value;

         img.src = "<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) %>" + a;
    }
</script>
```

.CS File

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected string UploadFolderPath = "~/Files/";
protected static int a = 0;
protected void fileUploadComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        string s = "abc" + a + "" + extension;

        btnhidden.Value = s;
        fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(this.UploadFolderPath) + s);
        a++;
}
```

I am trying to set value to hidden filed on server side fileuploadcompleted event and access it on client side on completed event..
but on client side hidden filed value return null..
so please suggest me how can perform this whole operation.
thank you.

Comment: The problem is because on the postback the value gets cleared, so my advise is get the value in session instead of getting it in the hidden field, so that the value remains in the session and you can use it in for your further operation..!!

Comment: First time session return null value for 1st image upload, for 2nd image upload it return 1st value that store in session..session value updated on 2nd post-back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function uploadControlUploadComplete(sender, e) {
            var imageID = sender.get_id().replace("afuUploadedImage", "imgUploadedImage");
            var fileName = e.get_fileName();
            $get(imageID).src = "TempFiles/" + fileName;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"
                EnablePageMethods="true">
            </ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

            <ajaxtoolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="afuUploadedImage" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="afuUploadedImage_UploadedComplete"
                OnClientUploadComplete="uploadControlUploadComplete" ThrobberID="lblThrobber" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblThrobber" runat="server" Style="display: none">
            <img src="image/indicator.gif"  alt="loading" /> 
            </asp:Label>
            <asp:Image ID="imgUploadedImage" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void afuUploadedImage_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (afuUploadedImage.HasFile)
    {
        afuUploadedImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/") + afuUploadedImage.FileName);
    }
}
```

Please try with the above code snippet and let me know if any concern.

**Update 1:**

**ASPX**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }
        function uploadControlUploadComplete(sender, e) {
            var name = readCookie("tabs").replace("url=", "");
            var imageID = sender.get_id().replace("afuUploadedImage", "imgUploadedImage");
            var fileName = e.get_fileName();
            $get(imageID).src = "TempFiles/" + name;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"
                EnablePageMethods="true">
            </ajaxtoolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

            <ajaxtoolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="afuUploadedImage" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="afuUploadedImage_UploadedComplete"
                OnClientUploadComplete="uploadControlUploadComplete" ThrobberID="lblThrobber" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblThrobber" runat="server" Style="display: none">
            <img src="image/indicator.gif"  alt="loading" /> 
            </asp:Label>
            <asp:Image ID="imgUploadedImage" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void afuUploadedImage_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (afuUploadedImage.HasFile)
    {
        string str = Guid.NewGuid() + "jayesh.jpg";
        afuUploadedImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/") + str);
        HttpCookie ActiveTabs = new HttpCookie("tabs");
        ActiveTabs.Values["url"] = str;
        Response.Cookies.Add(ActiveTabs);
    }
}
```

Comment: By using above code you can able to save the file in TempFiles folder and it show that image in the page also.

Comment: Hi Jayesh,
the above code worked properly but I want to change image name before upload it on server..
Please check my above question.
My code works properly but its not show image because I am changed image name before upload.

Comment: I have updated my above code. I have achieved same thing with the coockie.

Comment: hello Jayesh,
thank you man..Its working perfectly using cookie concept :)

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden field's value is null on client since AsyncFileUpload control uploading file in hidden frame. Try to add this line of code at the end of `fileUploadComplete` method:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), 
    "SetUploadedFileName", String.Format("top.$get('{0}').value = '{1}'", 
    btnhidden.ClientID, s), true);
```

Comment: Hi Yuriy,
I am trying but still hidden field return null value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadComplete(sender, e) {
        debugger;
        var imageID = sender.get_id().replace("afuUploadedImage", "imgUploadedImage");
        var fileName = e.get_fileName();
        $('#img5').attr('src', "/HomeImages/" + fileName);
    }

</script>
```

```
    <div class="span12">
        <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" hrobberID="myThrobber"
            ContextKeys="fred"
            MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" />
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <img src="" id="img5" />
    </div>
</div>
```